# Get data about tomorrow's weather from JSON 5 days forecast

Tags: java, json, datetime, openweathermap

Hello :) I am writing a telegram bot that shows todays and tomorrows weather. As data I'm using openweathermap.org.

For now I did getTodaysWeather method that get info about Java Objects from JSON on http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org and wrote this:

```
public class Weather {

    public static final String URL_SOURCE = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";
    public static final String API_KEY = "&APPID=3ad54740fd37f3f14a3a32a09f09cd25";
    public static final String UNITS = "&units=metric";
    public static final String LANG = "&lang=ru";

    public static String getWeather(String message) throws IOException{

        URL url = new URL(URL_SOURCE + message + LANG + UNITS + API_KEY);

        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());

        Scanner in = new Scanner((InputStream) url.getContent());
        String result = "";

        while (in.hasNext()) {
            result += in.nextLine();
        }

        OneDayWeather obj = null;
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = result;

        obj = gson.fromJson(json, OneDayWeather.class);

        System.out.println("City " + obj.getName() + "(" + obj.getSys().getCountry()+ ")" + "today's "+ System.lineSeparator() +
                "Temperature: " + obj.getMain().getTemp() + "°C, " + System.lineSeparator()+
                "Humidity: " + obj.getMain().getHumidity() + "%, " + System.lineSeparator()+
                "Rain: " + obj.getWeather().get(0).getDescription()+ System.lineSeparator()+
                "Wind speed: " + obj.getWind().getSpeed() + " m/s";
    }
}
```

Now I need to write a method that get tomorrow's weather data from this JSON data
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London&APPID=21f2aefa331b0d3f72e50b14a06ff983
If I think right I need to find the block in data that has date close to "tomorrow 1:00pm" and Get info about temperature, humidity, wind etc.
Every block starts with ""dt": 1547672400". I think it means date and time in different format. If it so, I need to find the right block and skip the other.

Unfortunately I don't know how to realise this method.
If someone could help me I would be very thankful :)

Comment: You should read the API documentation properly, they seem to have an endpoint called for a 5-day forecast

Comment: The API Docs seem quite clear: https://openweathermap.org/forecast5#JSON - `list.dt Time of data forecasted, unix, UTC`

Comment: You seem to know how to parse JSON in general - what exactly is the problem with this specific structure?

Comment: I did read it. Don't know how to write the code to find "tomorrow 13:00"

Comment: `dt` is unix time at UTC. Look up `unix time` if you don't know what that is

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to [convert](https://www.epochconverter.com/) "tomorrow 1:00pm" to a UTC and then to unix timestamp. Store this value as `tomorrow13Unix`.

Now for each forecast in the list, you compare it to `tomorrow13Unix` and if it is the same, you have found what you are looking for.

**Note** that the API splits the times into chunks of three, so you may want to instead look for the largest time that is **not** greater than `tomorrow13Unix`.

---

Here is how I would obtain the epoch time for tomorrow at 1pm:

```
long tomorrow13Unix = java.time.OffsetDateTime.now(java.time.ZoneOffset.UTC).with(java.time.LocalTime.of(13, 0)).plusDays(1).toEpochSecond();
```

#### Note

The above will get the current time at UTC, truncate that time to 1pm then add one day. This might not be what you want. You may want to instead use your local time, add one day to it, truncate to 1pm, and convert the resulting time to UTC, in which case you may want to use this instead:

```
long tomorrow13Unix = java.time.LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1).with(java.time.LocalTime.of(13, 0)).toEpochSecond(java.time.ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Comment: Unfotrunatelly I cant just set "17 January 1:00 pm". The method should do following: 1) get current date 2) add +1 day 3) search in JSON unix date timestrap that close to "current date +1 day" + 1:00pm. This is how I think to do it

Comment: what I did is: `Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date today = calendar.getTime();

        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        Date tomorrow = calendar.getTime();
        System.out.println(tomorrow);`

Comment: I think I need to write method to find tomorrow 1:00 pm (for today it's 17.01.2019 1:00pm, tomorrow it'll be 18.01.2019 1:00 pm). But how to do it?

Comment: @MichaelBlala avoid using deprecated date utilities. I updated my answer to show how to obtain the time for the next day (note the use of recommended `java.time.*` utilties)